# Tor browser updates itself despite the updates are disabled

Tags: help

I have torbrowser-install-6.0.3_en-US.exe and the updates are disabled: tools --> options --> advanced --> update --> never check for update. Nevertheless after a while Tor browser reposts me that it has downloaded and installed updates (6.0.5) and need to be restarted. Is there a way to forbid the Tor browser unauthorized update activity? The Tor browser is not functional after the update and I have to delete it and reinstall torbrowser-install-6.0.3_en-US.exe. This is very annoying.

Thank you in advance,

--
Mike

Comment: Instead, figure out what's going wrong with 6.0.5. You should not run 6.0.3 unless you like being infected with malware.

Comment: Could anyone answer just my original question: Is there a way to forbid the Tor browser unauthorized update activity?

Answer (score 1):

> I have torbrowser-install-6.0.3_en-US.exe and the updates are disabled: tools --> options --> advanced --> update --> never check for update.

After you start fresh installed old version of browser you need to change this option as fast as you could to do and restart browser after that without any delay.

Or add changed pref to ***prefs.js*** file after you installed old version of browser and before you run it.

> user_pref("app.update.auto", false);
>   user_pref("app.update.enabled", false);

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a fae Tor Browser distro, I helped people who had either Tor Browser, or the `tor.exe` binary replaced by a hoax program mimicing to the normal binary. Reinstall it from scratch and please tell how you have obtained this distro? What is your OS? I'll be able to help you in troubleshooting then

Comment: I believe it was here https://dist.torproject.org/torbrowser/. The exact link https://dist.torproject.org/torbrowser/6.0.3/ is not available anymore but the google cache https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:tkttbstyekIJ:https://dist.torproject.org/torbrowser/6.0.3/+&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk still lists it.

Comment: I have made sure to point out the installer name to minimize misunderstanding. The OS is Windows Server 2012 (Windows 8 analogue). The application is not tor.exe but firefox.exe. It is the foe indeed: if I occasionally press the Shift key during it's start it is switched to the firefox mode and it looks like there is no way to switch it back to the Tor mode -- complete reinstall only;

Comment: if I change some setting (use hardware acceleration or do not disturb me with the notification that I have changed my Tor browser window size and it may kill the Internet) I am guaranteed to end up with the complete reinstall -- it just crashes on the start up and does not give me a chance to get the setting back. The upgrade leads the Internet connection issue (the Tor does not crash but cannot connect to the Internet). I need the Tor browser for exactly one site and I even may get used to its quirks but it would be much easier if it stops pretend to be the Windows 10

Comment: and respect my desire to have 6.0.3.

Comment: Sorry for multiple comments. I could never have imagined there is a limitation on the post size.

Comment: No problems! I think - if you're using a server OS, then you should make a Hyper-V container for a router which redirects all the traffic through Tor and in second container you set up your browser for private browsing. And no leak possible even from IE. If you need further instructions - just drop me a line! I'll be glad to help

Comment: > And no leak possible even from IE. If you need further instructions - 
> just drop me a line! I'll be glad to help
Thank you. I do not need privacy indeed. I need a tool that will allow me to see the sites that my ISP is required to block by the government that takes care of me having been carefully brain washed.